# How to create a package in an hierarchical view in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am using `Eclipse juno`. I have started learning `java` and I am facing an issue in creating `package` within the package. I am getting a flat view of the packages. I want to create a package `com.soft.entity` that is com package contains soft package which further contains entity package.

PFA the screenshot

***[image: Screenshot 1:]***

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

**screenshot 3**

[image]

**screenshot 4**

[image]

Any lead is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: right click > New > package

Comment: its not wroking .. its giving me the package in a flat view

Comment: Add an screenshot of the Java package creation dialog with the name you are using, I think that there is the problem.

Comment: I will catch u tomorrow. I have to go now

Answer (score 1):

Put the package name as:

```
com.soft.entity
```

In the option: File > New > Package

See my screenshot:

[image]

To see in hierarchical view see my screenshot:

[image]

You'll see the hierarchical structure when you added more packages, if you only have one, you'll see it in a single line.

For instance, adding a second package:

[image]

Comment: I just want to create com package inside it soft and inside it entity . how to do that. I am struggling here

Comment: Please, Follow my updated answer, I've added screenshots. And, please confirm if it is working

Comment: Take it easy, don't give up, just start from the beginning, I think that your problem is in the package dialog creation, use the "File" menu option, not the right click. Besides, you can create a class in your package to be sure that the package is correctly created.

Comment: Start at the beginning, remove all your packages, read again my post, and after first step, put in your question the screenshot with the Java package dialog and the package name you put.

Comment: @user3086014, When I said "Put the package name as 'com.soft.entity'" I meant write "com.soft.entity" as name for your package, that is, write the entire name including the dots, in your screenshot you only wrote "com".

Comment: there is no default package in my project

Comment: Yes, the default package is created automatically if you define a class without package, It's not your case, ignore it.